# Is it possible to read selected rows from an extremely huge dataset in R

Tags: r, import, dataset, bigdata

I am running into a big problem with importing data into **R**. The thing is the original dataset is over 5GB, which in no way I can read in my laptop with 4GB RAM in total. There are unknown number of rows in the dataset (at least thousands of rows). I was wondering if I could select say the first 2000 rows to load into **R** so the I can still fit the data into my working memory?

Comment: See the `nrows` argument to `read.table`.

Comment: yes use `read.table` and if you need to skip some number of rows down use `skip`.

Comment: another option is to store your data in a database and use sql from within r

Comment: Read the first 2000 rows in a shell and output it to a file.  Then, call that file into R.  It should be much faster that way.

Comment: You can also try `sqldf` package. It creates a data base from your file enabling you to query anything you want using SQL syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Scott mentioned, you can limit the number of rows read from a text file with the `nrows` to `read.table` (and its variants like `read.csv`).

You can use this in conjunction with the `skip` argument to read later chunks in the dataset.

```
my_file <- "my file.csv"
chunk <- 2000
first <- read.csv(my_file, nrows = chunk)
second <- read.csv(my_file, nrows = chunk, skip = chunk)
third <- read.csv(my_file, nrows = chunk, skip = 2 * chunk)
```

You may also want to read the "Large memory and out-of-memory data" section of the [high-performance computing task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Comment: Just a note: `2e4` is 20,000. OP asked for 2,000